# Bootstrap Carousel Image filter

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I hope this question might be asked before. I have one problem with bootstrap carousel. I explain in detail what I want to achieve.

1. Let's say I have 10 images carousel slider.
2. When I click on second slide dots navigation one slide goes up and next slide comes in view.
3. If I click on number 9 slide dots navigation still One slide will go up and next slide will come in view.
4. I want when I click let's say number 5 slide dots navigation it should go up all way and let user know that slider moves 4 slides up/down and then reach on number 5 slide, however bootstrap carousel does not do that.
5. How can I achieve this effect.

for the sake of simplicity check this example. what I want to achieve 
http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#firstPage

Your help will be highly appreciate.

Many thanks

Comment: Update Your Query with Code

Comment: Thanks for reply N.V.Prasad. But how can I do it. Can you explain little bit. Here is js fiddle code. https://jsfiddle.net/magtechpro/f173438f/. I will appreciate if you help me.

Comment: got it just update this fiddle in your code as your research part where you can get help in to fiddle savable on your Name :-)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mmfansler/2zosm3s6/ ,http://jsfiddle.net/tutorialdrive/02ejafuv/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=02ejafuv - take a look at it

Comment: I did not get what are you trying to say. I researched and found this vertical slider and make some changes. If it is your code Thanks for this. My question is still there how we can filter through slides as I asked in question. Help me out please if you understand my question.

Comment: Honestly speaking i am an angular developer .  searched something as per your requirement posted as little bit help  pal ..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#fullpage').fullpage({
        slideSelector: '.slidefullpage',
    });
```

This is happening because bootstrap has the same class "slide" for sliders as Fullpage Js.
so, this will help